# How to assign value to function(transfer) 's parameter

Tags: solidity

I use these codes(@Lauri Peltonen ) however  I tried `5 ether` and `500`, but I found it had an error in remix " like I need to add payable to constructor, but I already added". What does that mean?

```
  pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

    contract MyContr {
        function transfer(address payable receiver, uint amount) public {
            require(address(this).balance >= amount);
            receiver.transfer(amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does you deployed smart contract has enough ether on balance to transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little you have shared, I assume you have provided no way to fund your contract or didn't fund it at all.

If you have indeed added the *payable* keyword to the constructor, you just need to set the transaction's value to what you desire at the moment of deploying the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContr {

    //Allows you to fund the contract with ether at the moment of deployement
    //You need to set the value of the transaction
    constructor() public payable {}

    function transfer(address payable receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount);
        receiver.transfer(amount);
    }
    //Payable function that allows you to directly send ether to the contract
    //without calling a specific function
    function() external payable {}
}
```